# how to convert multi element object to one element object

Tags: javascript

I have object like this

```
[
  { A: '1' },
  { B: '2' },
  { C: '3' },
]
```

I want convert to like this

```
{
  A: '1',
  B: '2',
  C: '3',
}
```

what is the best way to do it

Comment: Take a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Comment: What do you want to happen if there are two of the same keys in different objects

Comment: Best way? Do you know the worst way?

Comment: @ZachJensz  well, its obvious I am not at good point , let me think about it :D

Answer (score 1):

- Object.assign with spread syntax

```js
let arr = [
  { A: '1' },
  { B: '2' },
  { C: '3' },
]

console.log(Object.assign(...arr));
```

Comment: It's notable, that this mutates the first object in the original array. If that's not desirable, pass an empty object as `this` argument to `.assign` (`Object.assign({}, ...arr)`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [
  { A: '1' },
  { B: '2' },
  { C: '3' },
]

let output = {}

arr.map((obj) => {
    output = {...output, ...obj}
})

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Object.assign and spread operator will do the trick :

```
let arrObject = [
   { A: "1" }, 
   { B: "2" },
   { C: "3" }
];
```

1. `Object.assign(target, ...sources)`

`let obj = Object.assign({}, ...arrObject);`

`console.log(obj) => obj = { A: '1', B: '2', C: '3' }`